# OxyPlot. How to set DateTimeAxis range?

Tags: oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot to plot the amount of something in a certain range of time.

The possibilities for the 3 different time ranges I'm using are:

- One day, two days to 31 days, and 1 year to 4 years.
- For one day the plot always have to show 0 to 24h.
- For two days to 31 days I want to set for example the first day like 1 Jan then at the next tick 15 Jan and the last 30 Jan.

For one year to 4 years I want to set for example 4 ticks with just 2011 2012 2013 2014.

Is this possible somehow with just set start and end time and interval and string Format?

Is it possible to set the start time and end time ?

Comment: As far as I understood, the DateTimeAxis is not very flexible. When working with dates, and in need of some custom thing, I actually end up using a CategoryAxis and pass the DateTime values as formatted string. I guess you can workout something to show a value only when you need, and hence have irregular tick steps